# Tab bar controller need to tap 2 times return main view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have setup a tab bar view controller and linked with navigation controller,

refer to this image.
[image]
 The issue I'm facing is this image is "more" tab bar page 
[image]
  when I click the cross button, it will push to home view controller to another view. But when I hit another tab and come back to more tab, the view controller stil stay at the home view controller instead of more tab origin controller. I need to hit more tab 2 times then it only will back to more tab view controller. Below code is my tab bar controller when selecting item.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %ld", (long)item.tag);

    if (item.tag == 0) {
    //try to dismiss home view controller in this way, but it won't work
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        NSString *str = @"TAB 1";
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Conform protocol on appdelegte or subclass of UITabViewController

```
<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Assign delegate

```
tabBarController.delegate = self

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Swift 4.1 iOS 11.2

```
class TabBarMenuView: UITabBarController {

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if (self.selectedViewController?.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self))!
        {
            let nav = self.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
            nav.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method to UITabBarControllerDelegate

**override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem){enter following code in this method}**

```
    if item.tag < self.viewControllers!.count {
        if let nav = self.viewControllers![item.tag] as? UINavigationController {
            nav.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
```